# What is correct content-type for excel files?

Tags: excel, mime-types

I want excel files on a website to open in Excel when clicked, not get saved on desktop, or get opened embedded in a browser etc. Now obviously it all depends on how everything is configured for each user, but what's the best Content-Type and other settings to achieve just that most of the time?

Comment: Although this is a duplicate, I think it should be kept around as a pointer to the linked duplicate. The titles are sufficiently different.

Comment: [Office 2007 File Format MIME Types for HTTP Content Streaming](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsofficedeveloper/2008/05/08/office-2007-file-format-mime-types-for-http-content-streaming-2/)

Answer (score 1112, accepted):

For BIFF .xls files

```
application/vnd.ms-excel
```

For Excel2007 and above .xlsx files

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

Comment: This does not work for me when using IE9. Chrome, Opera, Safari, Firefox - no problem. But IE fails to recognize the `Content-type` and I have checked with the debugger in IE to confirm that the Content-type is `application/vnd.ms-excel`. I have also tested lower/upper cased headers. Anyone experienced this?

Comment: @luttkens - That'll be an issue with the combination of headers that you send, these are still the valid Content Types for Excel files

Comment: @MarkBaker You're right. When I removed `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='foo.xls'` it worked. But it doesn't really make me like IE...

Comment: For anyone out there wondering: by removing the single-quotes around foo.xls from the `Content-Disposition` even IE will recognize how to open it.

Comment: Hi, do you know the Content-Type of .xlsx files generated by Google Docs? I've tried your answer but no luck.

Comment: I had an issue where I could not open this file type after downloading it programmatically.  Basically it would save the file correctly, but when I did response.Transmitfile(..filepath..) where filepath was a legit filepath to a non-corrupted excel file, it would return a corrupted file.  Changing response.ContentType from "plain/text" to "application/nvd.ms-excel" fixed it.

Comment: .docx is worse application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

Comment: what is content type for office 365 excel files ?

Comment: @user1016740 Office 365 files are OfficeOpenXML-format .xlsx files, so it's `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

Comment: (+1) With Mac system ,if you are getting additional (.xls) ,Then adding the second content type (application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet ) will fox it

Comment: @Confused - a ___second___ Content Type will simply overwrite the first, you can only have  single content type header

Comment: @MarkBaker  I mean second line (i.e.application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet) of the above answer, rather then first one(application/vnd.ms-excel).

Comment: Why do they use such an ugly thing as this?

Comment: @Hinrich - because those ugly things tell the browser how to handle the data that you're sending it

Comment: For those who are ignorant like me and weren't really sure what BIFF is, the following may help *"XLS is the file extension of the Microsoft Excel spreadsheet. It is created in the versions of Excel prior to 2007. It is a binary format based upon Binary Interchange File Format (BIFF) and thus it stores information in binary format."*

Comment: @MarkBaker, and how do you figured this out?

Answer (score 47):

```
application/vnd.ms-excel
```

- `vnd class` / vendor specific
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#File_formats

Comment: File formats listed above. For http content-type see [Office System File Format MIME Types](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309278(office.12).aspx)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types

Answer (score 20):

Do keep in mind that the `file.getContentType` could also output **application/octet-stream** instead of the required **application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet** when you try to upload the file that is already open.