# Convert google spreadsheet to xls in google script

Tags: google-apps-script

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google apps script to email google spreadsheet excel version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712137/google-apps-script-to-email-google-spreadsheet-excel-version)

I looked everywhere for this but cannot get it to work. I am sending an email with an attachment in google app script. The document is a google spreadsheet. It currently sends as a pdf, however, I would like it to send as a xls. When I run the below code, I get "Unsupported Conversion requested". How can I send it as an xls?

```
function practiceMail() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange();
var file = DocsList.getFileById(docID);
var attachment = file.getAs('application/vnd.ms-excel');
var myFile = [file];

MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {attachments:myFile, mimetype:application/vnd.ms-  excel });
}
```

Comment: You're right, first answerer used it as reference in his post... which wasn't a good idea since the answer was not true anyway... thx for the heads up :-)

Comment: Here's a similar question with an up-to-date answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31809987/google-app-scripts-email-a-spreadsheet-as-excel

Answer (score 1):

Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712137/google-apps-script-to-email-google-spreadsheet-excel-version/12712966#12712966) for an explanation. In short, the answer is no. You cannot do this. However, there is an [open issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=585) which you can star to request this feature.