# Error uploading .xls file and converting to Google Spreadsheet via GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-drive-api

### Prior Research

Please do not close this question as a duplicate because my question deals with how to resolve the specific error message I am receiving and not the general question of whether my objective is achievable or not — as some other related questions, yielded by my research and below detailed, have asked.

#### Related questions and why they do not apply here

1. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681873/converting-xls-to-google-spreadsheet-in-google-apps-script) question, asked 7/27/2012, does not apply because it: (1) is too old (after 10 months, new solutions/methods might exist) and (2) does not deal with the specific error message I am experiencing.
2. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854490/convert-google-spreadsheet-to-xls-in-google-script) question, asked 10/12/2012, fails to apply for similar reasons.
3. My below code was copied from [here](https://gist.github.com/juanpabloaj/4666836) which was forked from [here](https://gist.github.com/rcknr/4414152). These are presumably, working solutions because they have been referenced as such from other question/answer exchanges here on Stack Overflow.

### Objective

Programmatically, I am trying to:

1. Search my email inbox.
2. Find Excel (.xls) file attachments.
3. Upload those .xls file attachments to Google Drive.
4. While uploading, convert the .xls files into a Google Spreadsheet file format.

### Problem

When I execute processInbox() (code shown at the bottom of this question), it fails and I get the error message shown below.

### Error Message

```
Request failed for returned code 403.
Server response:
{
   "error":{
      "errors":[
         {
            "domain":"usageLimits",
            "reason":"accessNotConfigured",
            "message":"AccessNotConfigured"
         }
      ],
      "code":403,
      "message":"AccessNotConfigured"
   }
}
(line 13, file "DriveUpload")
```

## Question

What am I doing wrong? And how can I fix it?

For example, do I need to do something special in my API [console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) relative to setting up my project to, say, access Google Drive or something? What am I missing?

Note: I have not yet successfully implemented oAuth in any of my applications, yet.

### Error Source

#### Line 13

(This is the code line referenced by the error message.)

```
var uploadRequest = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files/?uploadType=media&convert=true&key="+key, params); // convert=true convert xls to google spreadsheet
```

### Code

The complete body of code I am working with is shown below for your reference. I extracted the error-triggering, “line 13,” and highlighted it above to help us focus on the proximate cause of the problem.

DriveUpload.js

```
function uploadXls(file) {
  authorize();
  var key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // <-- developer key
  var metadata = { title: file.getName() }
  var params = {method:"post",
                oAuthServiceName: "drive",
                oAuthUseToken: "always",
                contentType: "application/vnd.ms-excel",
                contentLength: file.getBytes().length,
                payload: file.getBytes()
               };
  // convert=true convert xls to google spreadsheet
  var uploadRequest = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files/?uploadType=media&convert=true&key="+key, params);
  var uploadResponse = Utilities.jsonParse(uploadRequest.getContentText());
  var params = {method:"put",
                oAuthServiceName: "drive",
                oAuthUseToken: "always",
                contentType: "application/json",
                payload: Utilities.jsonStringify(metadata)
               };
  var metaRequest = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/"+uploadResponse.id+"?key="+key, params)
  return DocsList.getFileById(uploadResponse.id);
}

function authorize() {
  var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("drive");
  var scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive";
  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://accounts.google.com/OAuthAuthorizeToken");    
  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");  
}

function processInbox() {
  // get all threads in inbox
  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    // get all messages in a given thread
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    // iterate over each message
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      // log message subject
      var subject = messages[j].getSubject()
      //Logger.log(subject);
      if ( subject == "with xls attach" ){
        Logger.log(messages[j].getSubject());
        var attach = messages[j].getAttachments()[0];
        var name = attach.getName();
        var type = attach.getContentType();
        //var data = attach.getDataAsString();
        Logger.log( name + " " + type + " " );
        var file = uploadXls(attach);
        SpreadsheetApp.open(file);
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drive API is already built in GAS: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/

Use DriveApp and your problems go away ;-)

Comment: How did you get the file to convert using DriveApp? Was it with `getAs(contentType)` on the file?

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a temp solution

Step 1: Use a Google Form to Collect Data to a Google spreadsheet

Step 2: Add the Zoho Sheet App to your Google Drive

In a Zoho Sheet
Goto
Data Menu
  »Link External Data
Select either
CSV
RSS/Atom Feed
or HTML Page

You can schedule it to update at specific time intervals

What I like is the VBA and Macros in Zoho
You can also do Pivot Charts and Tables

You can copy and paste Excel VBA into Zoho !
I have an Unpivot VBA that I will run on my Tabular dataset
before I can do a PivotChart

It is hard to beat all the functionality of Excel and I often fall back on familiar tools !
If I hear of anything I will post it

Good luck