# How to save html table in Excel

Tags: php, codeigniter, export-to-excel

I have been trying to save html data in excel format(export to excel functionality basically) in PHP. I achieved that by changing header to

```
                header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
                header("Pragma: no-cache");
                header("Expires: 0");
```

But on opening the file, it shows a warning for above excel 2003 applications. So can I save the excel in 2008 or 2010 format just by modifying the header or do I have to go for other frameworks providing this feature like "PHPExcel" or something. And yes, I am using CodeIgniter for my website

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937465/what-is-correct-content-type-for-excel-files i think its just using the proper content type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use some libraries to generate Excel tables.

Standart HTML output is not converted automatically to the specified format if you only set the Content-Type you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the MIME type to:

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

instead of

```
application/vnd.ms-excel
```