# Safari appending .pdf extension

Tags: macos, excel, pdf, safari

I didn't know where else to ask this, so hopefully someone can assist…

I am downloading an Excel file using Safari, but when it downloads it saves the file as "MyFile.xls.pdf". When I download the same file using Chrome, then it saves it correctly as "MyFile.xls".

Any ideas where the additional extension is coming from and how do I turn it off?

I am running OSX 10.8.5, Safari 6.1.1.

Thanks,

Update: 
This is the output from the Network Headers in Chrome.

```
Request URL:https://www.mysecurewebsite.comreportpath=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Clients\My%20Site\Portal\TempUpload\xhglwh5pkevgbfzspcnk5b0y\DownloadedReport\ClubMembers_0000219.xls
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=xhglwh5pkevgbfzspcnk5b0y; __utma=233308684.875604932.1381860518.1389116164.1389130065.3; __utmb=233308684.1.10.1389130065; __utmc=233308684; __utmz=233308684.1381860518.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
Host:mysecuresite.com
Referer:https://www.mysecurewebsite.com
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
reportpath:C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Clients\My Site\Portal\TempUpload\xhglwh5pkevgbfzspcnk5b0y\DownloadedReport\ClubMembers_0000219.xls
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:private
content-disposition:attachment;filename=ClubMembers_0000219.xls
Content-Length:25119
Content-Type:application/pdf; charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 07 Jan 2014 22:07:37 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Comment: Can you inspect the request and see what MIME type the file has? Maybe extension and MIME type don't match and one browser is trying to fix it while the other doesn't.

Comment: I;ve updated my question with the content. Is it the "Content-type" do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file has a wrong content type (PDF) and Safari tries to fix this by appending the `.pdf` extension. Chrome doesn't do that. I don't think there is a *right* way for a browser to behave in this situation, the problem really lies with the content provider. The correct content type for Excel files can be found in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937465/what-is-correct-content-type-for-excel-files).

Comment: So hopefully I am correct in saying, the issue is not my browser/environment but is a problem with the source website and the content-typet that it has defined?