# How do i upload a local excel file to SAS

Tags: excel, sas, excel-2010, proc

I'm trying to upload a local `.xls`/`.xlsx` file to SAS using `Proc Upload`. Although the code seams to work and the file uploads, when i download it again to my desktop and open it... it fails as currupt!

```
rsubmit;
Proc Upload
  infile="C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Book1.xls"
  outfile='Book1.xls';
run;
endrsubmit;
```

SAS Version: 9.3 64-bit
MS Office: 2010 32-bit
OS: Windows 7 64-bit

What i'm trying to acheive is... upload the file to the server, attach it to email and send and then delete is from the server.

Comment: Try adding `BINARY` to the `PROC UPLOAD` statement, after the `outfile=` option, but before the semicolon.

Comment: Although the file has uploaded, when sent via email is is currupt! 

/*
rsubmit;
filename outmail email
subject=%unquote(%str(%'Cars &date%'))
TO= ("email")
CC= ("email")
attach=("cars &date..xlsx");
DATA _NULL_;
FILE outmail;
PUT "Hello All,";
PUT " ";
PUT %unquote(%str(%'Please find attached the Cars report for &date%'));
PUT " ";
PUT "Regards";
PUT "J";
PUT " ";
RUN;
*/

Comment: Try `attach=("cars &date..xlsx" ct="application/octet-stream");`. If the `application/octet-stream` doesn't work, use one of the codes referenced in this SO question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937465/what-is-correct-content-type-for-excel-files)

Comment: How could you suggest deleating the file SAS server once, the email is sent and file is no longer required?

Comment: Google "sas file delete" and look at the first link, a page describing the `FDELETE` function.