# file upload not working for doc, excel file

Tags: php, ajax

I am using below code for file upload but it do not work in case of doc and excel file

```
switch(strtolower($ImageType))
        {
            case 'image/png':
            case 'image/gif':   
            case 'application/pdf':
            case 'image/jpeg':
            case 'video/avi':
            case 'video/mp4':
            case 'image/pjpeg':
            case 'application/msword':
            case 'application/vnd.ms-excel':
                break;
            default:
                die('Unsupported File!'); //output error and exit
        }
```

this code work i case of image but when we upload doc file. it show me unsupported file

Comment: How are you determining the `$ImageType` ? Can you post that code ?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing additional MIME types. Your MIME types are correct for older .doc and .xls files, but not for newer ones.

For .xlsx files use:

`application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

For .docx files use:

`application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`

This might help you as well:

- [What is a correct mime type for docx, pptx etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212861/what-is-a-correct-mime-type-for-docx-pptx-etc)
- [What is correct content-type for excel files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937465/what-is-correct-content-type-for-excel-files)