# Excel .xlsx file not opening after downloading the file from the server in java

Tags: java, excel, jakarta-ee, servlets

Here is my sample code. I am using eclipse , tomcat server .Browser as IE9.

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");


        ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Student> students = (List<Student>) context.getAttribute("students");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        for(Student student:students){
            out.println(student.getId()+"\t"+student.getName());
        }
        out.close();

    }
```

I am getting the List of Student. But when i am opening the downloaded file file getting error saying that file format or extention is not valid. My downloaded file is .xlsx .

Comment: Please look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937465/what-is-correct-content-type-for-excel-files

Comment: What you send is not an xslx file. You send a csv with tab as delimiter.

Comment: try application/vnd.ms-excel

Comment: @Jens where did you know that he sends a csv file??

Comment: @navin An xlsx file is in general a zip archive. Have you test it that is not corrupt?

Comment: @reporter OP prints `student.getId()+"\t"+student.getName()` as response.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to use [HSSFWorkbook](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html) class to create your excel file. After its created (for creation process see: [this example](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/04/16/poi_excel.html)) you can write its contents to response like this:

```
Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

// Add sheet(s), colums, cells and its contents to your workbook here ...

// First set response headers
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=YourFilename.xlsx");

// Get response outputStream
ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();

// Write workbook data to outputstream
workbook.write(outputStream);
```

Comment: in this way i will be creating a .xls file not .xlsx file. Here i want to create a .xlsx file

Comment: Sorry I misread that requirement. Then you simply use `XSSFWorkbook` class instead and change `YourFilename extension to xlsx. Both `HSSFWorkbook` and `XSSFWorkbook` are implementing Wokbook interface, so its api will be same.
See http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html
Updating answer

Answer (score 0):

It is not so much an .xlsx file, more a CSV or tab separated value text file. It fakes to be an Excel file; and yes, then Excel opens it correctly,

Try to read it with NotePad. You also can make a .xlsx file with NotePad to check whether the trick works.

The following tries:

- .xls
- A Windows `\r\n` (CR+LF) line ending. Maybe the server is Linux and delivers `\n` (LF).
- A defined encoding.

Then

```
    response.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");

    ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Student> students = (List<Student>) context.getAttribute("students");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.print("\uFEFF"); // UTF-8 BOM, redundant and ugly
    for(Student student:students){
        out.printf("%s\t%s\r\n", student.getId(), student.getName());
    }
    //out.close();
```

Comment: i have kept the response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"); unchanged.

Comment: when i am opening the same downloaded(.xlsx) file in notepad++ , able to view the content.

Comment: `response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=\"test.xsl\"";` or so? Try the (downloaded, edited) text file as .xsl and .xslx by double-clicking it.