# Creating Excel file using razor view defined structure

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget-package

I want to create an .xlsx file not .xls using my razor view string, But it doesn't work here is my code

```
private ContentResult GenerateExcel<T>(string viewName, T model) where T : class
    {
        var htmlViewRenderer = new HtmlViewRenderer();
        string htmlText = htmlViewRenderer.RenderViewToString(this, viewName, model);
        //  byte[] renderedBuffer;
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;

        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Marklist.xlsx");
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        Response.Charset = "";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        Response.Output.Write(htmlText.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
       return  Content(htmlText,Response.ContentType);

    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is correct content-type for excel files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937465/what-is-correct-content-type-for-excel-files)

Comment: @Pedro.The.Kid thanks but I already tried this but this does not work with XLSX format when i explicitly change extension for xlsx to xls it work

Comment: it states that for XLSX the content type is different

Answer (score 0):

IText-sharp comes with nuget package it helped to create excel i use it and it don't have any issue for  xls or xlsx format