# How to export all pages of gridview to excel without columns containing controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that has 2 columns that are a dropdownlist and upload control. I am trying to export the gridview to excel and the code works but it only works to export the current view not all the pages. When I try to export all pages the data binding fails and code crashes. Please help if you know a way of getting all the pages exported to excel/csv with or without the columns containing controls.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ExportBtn" runat="server" ImageUrl="../Images/ExcelIcon.jpg" Alt="Export" Width="40px" Height="40px" style="border-width:0px" onclick="ExportBtn_Click" />


protected void ExportBtn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{

        gv.Columns[7].Visible = false;
        gv.Columns[8].Visible = false;

        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Documents.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
        gv.AllowPaging = false;
        gv.DataBind();

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        Response.Charset = String.Empty;

        gv.RenderControl(htw);
        Response.Write(sw.ToString());

        Response.End();
    }
```

The error I get when I try to export all pages is:
Server Error in '...20150605_0846_local' Application.

'DocStatusDropDown' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'DocStatusDropDown' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value

Source Error: 


Line 194:        gvMainGrid.Columns[8].Visible = false;
Line 195:        gvMainGrid.AllowPaging = false;
Line 196:        gvMainGrid.DataBind();
Line 197:        Response.ClearContent();
Line 198:        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=MissingDocuments.xls");
```

Comment: You're using an incorrect content type for an excel document. Change it as appropriate according to the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937465/what-is-correct-content-type-for-excel-files

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Camilo, This is the error(posted above) I get when I try to export all pages otherwise it works fine to just export current view/page

Answer (score 1):

using [ExcelLibrary](https://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/) it's pretty easy to achieve it. But you needs to pass a dataSet to CreateWorkbook method.

```
    protected void CreateExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         List<Student> dataSource = (List<Student>)GrdData.DataSource; 
         DataSet ds = new DataSet("NewDataSet"); 
         DataTable dTable = ExtentionHelper.ToDataTable<Student>(dataSource);
         ds.Tables.Add(dTable);
         ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook("C://MyExcelFile.xlsx", ds);
      }
```

ExtentionHelper to get DataTable from `List<Student>`

```
public static class ExtentionHelper
    {
        public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("DataTable");
            Type t = typeof(T);
            PropertyInfo[] pia = t.GetProperties();

            //Inspect the properties and create the columns in the DataTable
            foreach (PropertyInfo pi in pia)
            {
                Type ColumnType = pi.PropertyType;
                if ((ColumnType.IsGenericType))
                {
                    ColumnType = ColumnType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                }
                dt.Columns.Add(pi.Name, ColumnType);
            }

            //Populate the data table
            foreach (T item in collection)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr.BeginEdit();
                foreach (PropertyInfo pi in pia)
                {
                    if (pi.GetValue(item, null) != null)
                    {
                        dr[pi.Name] = pi.GetValue(item, null);
                    }
                }
                dr.EndEdit();
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            return dt;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Shana, found another solution /work around before I got a chance to try out this code. I might use it in the future. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "Documents.xls"));
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);
gv.AllowPaging = false;
gv.RenderControl(hw);
Response.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.End();
```

Comment: Thank you! I still encounter the same problem with this solution. but I've found a work around and that's all I need.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all! I found a work around by duplicating the gridview without the trouble control columns and exporting it. Also turned the duplicate gv to not be displayed so no UI awkwardness.