# Excel found unreadable content in 'filename.xlsx' in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, excel

I upload all kind of applications (like pdf,excel, images and txt etc) to sql database. But when I download .xlsx file I am getting below error

`Excel found unreadable content in 'filename.xlsx'. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.`

While downloading I am using below code to download for all files.

```
 Dim decompressed As New AcedInflator
 Dim bytearr As Byte() = decompressed.Decompress(DirectCast(sqldr.Item(1), Byte()), 0, 0, 0)

 Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" & Filename)
 Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
  'Write Array to Browser
 Response.BinaryWrite(bytearr)
  written = True
```

What should I do?

Comment: i got this issue because it will download in excel as html table..if you press yes it will open but it annoys the user so i used OfficeOpenXml for excel download.

Comment: Use correct `Response.ContentType`

Refer to 
[Correct Content Type][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937465/what-is-correct-content-type-for-excel-files

Comment: @KailashPolai I did that too. Still didn't work