# Downloading excel file on Firefox

Tags: java, excel, firefox, download

I have to download the excel file upon the click of button my UI screen.I have used the below responseHeader and responseContentType.

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""
                    + excelfileName + "\"");
```

This funcationality works fine for IE and chrome, but not for firefox. For Firefox, it does download the excel but also gives the error on UI. The downloaded file is correct.

[image]

Comment: Might be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937465/what-is-correct-content-type-for-excel-files

Comment: This looks not like a default error message. "Reqest"? It looks like a JavaScript `alert` message. So please show the code which creates that alert.