# Excel not opening .xls made from C# StringBuilder

Tags: c#, excel, export, export-to-excel, stringbuilder

The following code was written several months ago and tested perfectly, with that funny little warning message in Excel.  Now, though, after the C# code runs without errors and the browser downloads the exported .xls file, the Excel application opens but displays nothing, as if it didn't open the exported file.  Can anyone see problems with this code or know why Excel suddenly wouldn't open this document?  Many thanks in advance!

The C# Code:

```
[HttpGet]
public void DownloadReport()
{
    string filename = "ReportExport";

    //Report source data organized here

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<table>");
    sb.Append("<tr>");
    foreach (DataColumn column in reportData.Columns)
    {
        sb.Append("<th>");
        sb.Append(column.ColumnName);
        sb.Append("</th>");
    }
    sb.Append("</tr>");
    foreach (DataRow row in reportData.Rows)
    {
        sb.Append("<tr>");
        foreach (DataColumn column in reportData.Columns)
        {
            sb.Append("<td>");
            if (row[column] == null)
            {
                sb.Append("");
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(row[column]);
            }
            sb.Append("</td>");
        }
        sb.Append("</tr>");
    }
    sb.Append("</table>");
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName + ".xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
    Response.Write(style);
    Response.Output.Write(sb.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: You are not generating a XLS file. The stated code generates a HTML fragment and tells the browser that this is a Excel file. Excel itself checks the data and cannot parse it (it is expecting binary data). Better use a Excel generator library.

Comment: @rboe - thank you for the response.  This code was previously generating an Excel file and is based on the principles explained here: http://www.icodefor.net/2016/07/export-data-to-excel-sheet-in-asp-dot-net-c-sharp.html.  The question is why would it work before and suddenly stop working?

Comment: this approach relies on the ability of Excel to discover automatically other formats (Text as HTML in this case) instead of the orginally format. I would not rely on that this autodiscovery feature will not change its behaviour over time.

Comment: Have you tried the earlier post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937465/what-is-correct-content-type-for-excel-files)

Comment: @Aishu - thanks for the response.  It looks like the correct content type is being used: "application/vnd.ms-excel"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `Response.ClearHeaders()` before setting the header seems to have done the trick.  Perhaps the content type had been previously specified and needed to be reset.

Answer (score 0):

You are not generating a XLS file. The stated code generates a HTML fragment and tells the browser that this is a Excel file. Excel itself checks the data and cannot parse it (it is expecting binary data). Better use a Excel generator library.

Have a look at [Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp?rq=1)

Personally I have made good experiences with NPOI and the Open XML SDK.

Comment: thank you for the response. This code was previously generating an Excel file and is based on the principles explained here: http://www.icodefor.net/2016/07/export-data-to-excel-sheet-in-asp-dot-net-c-sharp.html. The question is why would it work before and suddenly stop working?