# PHP: Exporting and importing MySQL table to excel

Tags: php, html, excel

I'm trying to export a table from MySql database to excel with PHP. But I'm getting the error that the file format or file extension is not valid. My current code is below:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$output = '';

$query = "SELECT * FROM  student_management_module";
$db->setQuery($query);
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();

$output .= '
    <table class="table" bordered="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Program</th>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th>Start Date</th>
            <th>End Date</th>
        </tr>
';

foreach ($rows as &$row) {
    $output .= '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$row->name.'</td>
            <td>'.$row->email.'</td>
            <td>'.$row->program.'</td>
            <td>'.$row->class.'</td>
            <td>'.$row->start_date.'</td>
            <td>'.$row->end_date.'</td>
            <td>'.$row->student_id.'</td>
    ';
}
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='download.xlsx");
header("Pragma: no-cache");

$output .= '</table>';
echo $output;
```

Thanks in advance, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Change the filename's extension from `.xlsx` to `.xls`.**

---

If you're still having problems after that, you may have an incorrect MIME type for an extension in the registry; repair steps and more information can be found in the below links.

---

- [**List of MIME Types and their associated extentions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types)
- Stack Overflow : [**What is a correct mime type for docx, pptx etc?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4212908/8112776)`
- Stack Overflow: [**What is correct content-type for excel files?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2938188/8112776)
- whatwg.org: [**Registry-MIME-types**](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Registry-MIME-types)
- Microsoft Docs : [**File Types: Set Subkeys and File Type Extension Attributes**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/fa-file-types#setting-optional-subkeys-and-file-type-extension-attributes)

    -

Comment: ok, I changed the content-type to "application/vnd.ms-excel" and filename to "download.xls" and it opens. But it gives a warning that the file format and extension of "download.xls" don't match. Also, when I open the excel file, there are no lines to seperate each cell.

Comment: If could be related to which version of Excel you are using, or the issue might be a registry setting. See the links I've added to the answer for more information.