# Content-Type: multipart/related

Tags: phpspreadsheet

I have this kind of Excel document and the file type is .xls. At least Excel complains about the file type that it doesn't match to the contents. Anyway, any idea how to import this with PhpSpreadsheet and what should be defined as a file type? I've tried guessing the file type with `IOFactory::identify` and it says `csv` but it couldn't be further from the truth. By the way, this file can be opened in a browser. Thanks!

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Document-Type: Worksheet
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="----=_NextPart_02231FF.FCECE"

------=_NextPart_01C5084F.CFF9A7A003434
Content-Location: file:///C:/xyz.htm
Content-Transfer-Encoding: text/html
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"

...
```

There are also several following NextParts in the document when opened in Notepad:

```
------=_NextPart_0CCCCCCF.FFFFFFF
Content-Location: file:///C:/image1.gif
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Type: image/gif
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is correct content-type for excel files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937465/what-is-correct-content-type-for-excel-files)

Comment: I don't see that as a duplicate.