# Special characteres not decoding

Tags: java, http-headers, postman

I'm generating a csv/xls file but when I use the postman to test the rest controller, I'm getting a lot of special chars but the file itself is being generated properly.
[image: image with spec chars]

so, the file generated has literally 3 lines and 2 rows.
these are my HttpHeaders:
-headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/csv;charset=ISO-8859-1");
-headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + fileName);

Comment: Looks like binary data shown as text. Does not make much sense to me.

Comment: Is this the output from the top? Or is it perhaps beginning with the letters PK?

Comment: What encoding is the controller using? You have a header specifying Latin1. Is that a request header or a response header? I'm guessing the latter, but I don't think your controller is really returning Latin1.

Comment: Hidden within the first line appear the letters "Root entry". This seems to be a binary .xls file (Excel versions before 2007)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is correct content-type for excel files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937465/what-is-correct-content-type-for-excel-files)

Comment: @DavidConrad Is a response header. How do I change the specifitacion of the header?

Comment: Change it to the content-type matching your actual content: [Excel content types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2938188/636009)

Comment: Still not working even changing to -> headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/vnd.ms-excel");

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? That Postman decode the binary? It will not, no matter the encoding.

Comment: Instead of sending the request, you click on the down-chevron to the right of the send button and save the response and open it in excel.

Comment: ok, I did that and there's a way to put the extension when I going to save the file?
https://imgur.com/1VU72Sm
When I debbug the code, I can see that the String with the file name is being saved wiht the properly extension (csv or xls)